# rake aborted! NoMethodError: undefined method `alias_method_chain' for ActiveRecord::SchemaDumper:Class

Tags: ruby, rails-upgrade, foreigner

when i added the foreigner gem in gemfile this occur and i am upgrading rails 4.1 to 6.1:
any solution anyone have fast post otherwise you can mail to santu.essence@gmail.com

/usr/local/bundle/bundler/gems/foreigner-0496762a6c0a/lib/foreigner/schema_dumper.rb:6:in `block in <module:SchemaDumper>' /usr/local/bundle/gems/activesupport-6.1.4.1/lib/active_support/concern.rb:136:in` class_eval'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/activesupport-6.1.4.1/lib/active_support/concern.rb:136:in `append_features' /usr/local/bundle/bundler/gems/foreigner-0496762a6c0a/lib/foreigner/loader.rb:9:in` include'
/usr/local/bundle/bundler/gems/foreigner-0496762a6c0a/lib/foreigner/loader.rb:9:in `block in load' /usr/local/bundle/bundler/gems/foreigner-0496762a6c0a/lib/foreigner/loader.rb:8:in` class_eval'
/usr/local/bundle/bundler/gems/foreigner-0496762a6c0a/lib/foreigner/loader.rb:8:in `load' /usr/local/bundle/bundler/gems/foreigner-0496762a6c0a/lib/foreigner/railtie.rb:5:in` block (2 levels) in class:Railtie'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/activesupport-6.1.4.1/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:71:in `class_eval' /usr/local/bundle/gems/activesupport-6.1.4.1/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:71:in` block in execute_hook'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/activesupport-6.1.4.1/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:61:in `with_execution_control' /usr/local/bundle/gems/activesupport-6.1.4.1/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:66:in` execute_hook'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/activesupport-6.1.4.1/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:52:in `block in run_load_hooks' /usr/local/bundle/gems/activesupport-6.1.4.1/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:51:in` each'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/activesupport-6.1.4.1/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:51:in `run_load_hooks' /usr/local/bundle/gems/activerecord-6.1.4.1/lib/active_record/base.rb:315:in` module:ActiveRecord'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/activerecord-6.1.4.1/lib/active_record/base.rb:15:in `<top (required)>' worker_1  | /usr/local/bundle/gems/zeitwerk-2.5.1/lib/zeitwerk/kernel.rb:35:in` require'
worker_1  | /usr/local/bundle/gems/zeitwerk-2.5.1/lib/zeitwerk/kernel.rb:35:in `require' worker_1  | /usr/local/bundle/gems/activerecord-6.1.4.1/lib/active_record/railtie.rb:132:in` block (3 levels) in class:Railtie'
worker_1  | /usr/local/bundle/gems/activesupport-6.1.4.1/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:71:in `class_eval' worker_1  | /usr/local/bundle/gems/activesupport-6.1.4.1/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:71:in` block in execute_hook'
worker_1  | /usr/local/bundle/gems/activesupport-6.1.4.1/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:61:in `with_execution_control' worker_1  | /usr/local/bundle/gems/activesupport-6.1.4.1/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:66:in` execute_hook'
worker_1  | /usr/local/bundle/gems/activesupport-6.1.4.1/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:43:in `block in on_load' worker_1  | /usr/local/bundle/gems/activesupport-6.1.4.1/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:42:in` each'
worker_1  | /usr/local/bundle/gems/activesupport-6.1.4.1/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:42:in `on_load' worker_1  | /usr/local/bundle/gems/activerecord-6.1.4.1/lib/active_record/railtie.rb:131:in` block (2 levels) in class:Railtie'
worker_1  | /usr/local/bundle/gems/activesupport-6.1.4.1/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:68:in `block in execute_hook' worker_1  | /usr/local/bundle/gems/activesupport-6.1.4.1/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:61:in` with_execution_control'
worker_1  | /usr/local/bundle/gems/activesupport-6.1.4.1/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:66:in `execute_hook' worker_1  | /usr/local/bundle/gems/activesupport-6.1.4.1/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:52:in` block in run_load_hooks'
worker_1  | /usr/local/bundle/gems/activesupport-6.1.4.1/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:51:in `each' worker_1  | /usr/local/bundle/gems/activesupport-6.1.4.1/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:51:in` run_load_hooks'
worker_1  | /usr/local/bundle/gems/railties-6.1.4.1/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:140:in `block in <module:Finisher>' worker_1  | /usr/local/bundle/gems/railties-6.1.4.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:32:in` instance_exec'
worker_1  | /usr/local/bundle/gems/railties-6.1.4.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:32:in `run' worker_1  | /usr/local/bundle/gems/railties-6.1.4.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:61:in` block in run_initializers'
worker_1  | /usr/local/bundle/gems/railties-6.1.4.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:60:in `run_initializers' worker_1  | /usr/local/bundle/gems/railties-6.1.4.1/lib/rails/application.rb:391:in` initialize!'
worker_1  | /usr/src/app/config/environment.rb:4:in `<top (required)>' worker_1  | /usr/local/bundle/gems/zeitwerk-2.5.1/lib/zeitwerk/kernel.rb:35:in` require'
worker_1  | /usr/local/bundle/gems/zeitwerk-2.5.1/lib/zeitwerk/kernel.rb:35:in `require' worker_1  | /usr/local/bundle/gems/activesupport-6.1.4.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:332:in` block in require'
worker_1  | /usr/local/bundle/gems/activesupport-6.1.4.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:299:in `load_dependency' worker_1  | /usr/local/bundle/gems/activesupport-6.1.4.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:332:in` require'
worker_1  | /usr/local/bundle/gems/railties-6.1.4.1/lib/rails/application.rb:367:in `require_environment!' worker_1  | /usr/local/bundle/gems/railties-6.1.4.1/lib/rails/application.rb:533:in` block in run_tasks_blocks'
worker_1  | /usr/local/bundle/gems/rake-13.0.6/exe/rake:27:in `<top (required)>'
worker_1  | Tasks: TOP => resque:work => resque:preload => resque:setup => environment
worker_1  | (See full trace by running task with --trace)

Comment: How did you _upgrading rails 4.1 to 6.1_? Did you do that in one step or in smaller steps? Did you do all the changes to your source code that are usually needed? Did you follow the [Rails Guides about how to update apps](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/upgrading_ruby_on_rails.html)?

Comment: `alias_method_chain` was deprecated in Rails 5. Given that the latest version of the [`foreigner` gem](https://github.com/matthuhiggins/foreigner) was released more than six years ago and hasn't been updated since it is probably safe to assume that this old gem doesn't work with up-to-date Rails versions anymore.

Comment: I already added all necessary configuration which required for rails 6 and I comment this gem in gemfile then bundle install after that my web app working properly but some feature not working like record not created and stored in database.

Comment: sir, any solution with foreigner gem and alternative gem you know then suggest me I really needed.

Comment: You might want to look on the [Ruby Toolbox](https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/categories/Active_Record_Index_Assistants) for alternatives. Perhaps one of them still supports the latest Rails version although most haven't been updated lately.